# Sails JS add routes dynamically

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js, node-modules

I'm trying to find a way to add routes dynamically outsides of the config/routes.js file.
I'm creating a module who need some routes and don't want to let the user add it manually under config/routes.js.

Is there a way to do this ? I look sails doc and maybe with hooks I can't achieve this but can't find how

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious What kind of routing path you want to create?

Remember that wildcard is available in `route.js`

```
'GET /validEmail/*', "VerificationController.verifyEmail"'
```

Comment: Yes I now but I'm creating a module for sails.js who make a basic back office for all models. So I want to add dynamically routes to back office and models pages. I don't want to make a README and let the user add the different routes.

Comment: I see, that will be more complex than I think, I have found the Sails saved the routing data in "sails.router.explicitRoutes", maybe that's where you can inject

Comment: Ho great I didn't find where sails put routes, I will look at it and let you know. 
One 'hack' I have found is to use sails hooks to inject routes, it's working very great but policies are not apply to them :/ so I can't use this solution.

Comment: maybe you could use a super route to to whatever you want ("/*"). it the request doesn't fit, redirect them to original route.